# Real time services monitoring using ELK Stack

Tags: elasticsearch, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, logstash, kibana

Is it possible to monitor the below **services** using ELK Stack ?

```
 1. Web Services
 2. Windows Services
 3. Scheduled Tasks
```

This will need to tell the service up or down.

Is it provide any **Real time alerts(email alert)** with Health Monitoring ?

Comment: Yes, ELK can easily monitor these services. Actually, to be more accurate, you can use ELK to monitor these services. You can buy Elasticsearch watcher or you can use services like http://Logz.io which offer it near-realtime alerts for ELK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic just launched [watcher](https://www.elastic.co/products/watcher), which is their version of alerting for the ELK stack.

It's not real-time, but rather makes periodic queries against elasticsearch.

If you want to make your own polling system, you can define your own queries (see the [elasticsearch-dsl python module](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py)) and return status and performance information to your existing monitoring system.  [More reading](http://svops.com/blog/monitoring-your-log-files/).

Comment: Thanks `@Alain Collins`, already i know about `watcher`. But i need the single solution for all requirements what i have been mentioned in above..What about to using `Nagios` service monitoring is your thoughts...